# Выполнить действие если есть какое либо число в span

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage, span

Есть тег span

```
<span class="t706__cartwin-prodamount"></span>
```

Который пустой, если нет никакого товара в корзине. Если добавляем товар в корзину то появляется цена и значение валюты (в данном случае рубль)

```
<span class="t706__cartwin-prodamount">295 ₽</span>
```

И в случае, если в теге span есть какое нибудь значение, то есть цена товара, то мы должны добавить класс   **active-cart-bg** с ссылкой на текущую страницу (это для того, чтобы можно было перейти на страницу с категориями товара на любой другой странице) объекту **cart-bg** и записать все это в local storage для того, чтобы было видно на других страницах сайта, что в корзине есть какой то товар.

Comment: Чтобы не дёргать каждый раз `span` каждые там 1000 мс. через setinterval, лучше завязать триггер на добавлении в таблицу. Напишите как Вы добавляете товар в карзину.

Comment: Функция, которая добавляет товар в корзину - сама заодно должна вызвать функцию, добавляющую все необходимые классы и ссылки. Все другие варианты - костыльные...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ладно, ввиду отсутствия комментариев со стороны ТС, предположим, что надо именно так, хотя я считаю это не совсем корректным. 
Как я писал ранее - я считаю, что необходимо завязаться на триггере добавления товара в корзину.

```js
<style>
    .active-cart-bg{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<span class="t706__cartwin-prodamount">123 .p</span>
<div class="cart-bg"></div>
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { // Отслеживаем загрузку контента. Если Вы уже проверяли контент, то в этой функции нет необходимости.
        let span1 = document.querySelector('.t706__cartwin-prodamount'); // Получаем элемент по классу
        let cart = document.querySelector('.cart-bg'); // Получаем div корзины по классу
        let checkSpan = function() { // Запускаем функцию
            if(span1.innerText != ''){ // Если текст внутри НЕ пустой, то.
                cart.className = cart.className+' active-cart-bg'; // Добавляем класс карзине. (Если заменить, а не добавлять, то cart.className = 'active-cart-bg';)
                let a = document.createElement('a'); // Создаём ссылку
                a.href = window.location.toString(); // Берём текущую ссылку страницы.
                a.innerText = span1.innerText; // Добавляем этой ссылке текст из спана (сумма) Можно добавлять любой другой текст.
                cart.appendChild(a); // Добавляем ссылку в div с корзиной.

                localStorage.setItem('active', 'yes'); // Записываем в localstorage, что корзина не пуста
                localStorage.setItem('href', window.location.toString()); // Записываем в корзинку ссылку.
                clearInterval(checkSpan); // Останавливаем выполнение функции
            } else { // Если текст пустой в теге, то...
                setTimeout(checkSpan, 1000); // Через секунду заного запускаем эту функцию. До тех пор, пока не появится текст в span
            }
        };
        checkSpan(); // Собственно запускаем функцию
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам. Я изменил условие, теперь если кол-во товаров в корзине больше одного, то срабатывает данный скрипт if(span1.innerText > 0) но проблема сейчас в ссылке, открывая главную создается ссылка главной страницы, а не страницы где были добавлены товары и еще при удалении всех товаров из корзины, класс все еще висит на bg-cart

Comment: @ДмитрийНевский Предполагалось, что находясь на странице товара Вы записываете в `localstorage` несколько элементов `href`. Например, `href1`, `href2`, `href3` и так далее по количеству товаров. либо в одно поле, то через сепаратор. `window.location` получает `url` именно текущей страницы. Если Вы на главной странице не вызываете скрипт, то всё должно работать корректно. Просто совершенно непонятно, как у Вас всё устроено, Вы этого, к сожалению, не написали. Что касается класса - можно либо завязать на кнопку удаления переключение класса, Либо опять так же проверять каждые n секунд `localstor

Comment: @ДмитрийНевский `localstorage` и, в случае отсутствия записей - убирать данный класс.